# Return result of uneven np.array multiplication and print ValueError

Tags: python, r, numpy

My desired output is essentially replicating how R handles uneven vectors. Below, R proceeds to complete the operation and reports back the error.

```
> x <- c(1,2,3)
> y <- c(4,5,6)
> xy <- x * y
> xy
[1]  4 10 18
> y <- c(4,5,6,7)
> xy <- x * y
Warning message:
In x * y : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> xy
[1]  4 10 18  7
>
```

In Python using numpy it works the same except that it throws a ValueError and stops.

```
xy = 0
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6,7]

In [21]: xy = np.array(x) * np.array(y)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-0fa98c7ea5af> in <module>()
----> 1 xy = np.array(x) * np.array(y)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,)
```

Is there a way to accept the error and produce the output and the ValueError, so that if I created a simple add or multiply function it would always return a value and not break on the ValueError?

```
 def vector_multiply(v, w):
         return np.array(v) * np.array(w)
```

Would return

```
 array([ 4, 10, 18, 6]
 ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,)
```

**EDIT**
possible solution based on comments

```
def vector_multiply(v, w):
    ...:     while length(v) == length(w):
    ...:         try:
    ...:             outarray = np.array(v) + np.array(w)           
    ...:             break
    ...:         except ValueError:
    ...:             print("ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes")
    ...:             if len(v) > len(w):
    ...:                 vmod = v[0:len(v) - a]
    ...:                 output = np.array(vmod) * np.array(w)
    ...:             else:
    ...:                 wmod = v[0:len(w) - a]
    ...:                 output = np.array(wmod) * np.array(v)
    ...:     return output
```

Comment: why not test lengths of v & w, slice the longer to the shorter then append the remainder of the longer to the resulting multiplication? I realize that isn't a general solution ( it's basically working like vectors in R vs multi-dimensional structures) but if you only need it to work like vectors it's prbly  a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

This task is known as 'exception handling'. You do it in Python like so:

```
def vector_multiply(v, w):
    try: 
        answer = np.array(v) * np.array(w)
    except ValueError:
        print "Warning: shapes didn't match"
        answer = #whatever you want instead
    return answer
```

Comment: displayed little information or effort comments proved more useful.

Comment: "Is there a way to accept the error and produce the output and the ValueError, so that if I created a simple add or multiply function it would always return a value and not break on the ValueError?"

The above is the solution to the question you asked...

Comment: really, I beg to differ showing a basic try except could answer a 100 question generally and useful in how many cases. hence my comment displayed little information or effort

Comment: "Is there a way to accept the error and produce the output and the ValueError, so that if I created a simple add or multiply function it would always return a value and not break on the ValueError?" The answer to this question is yes: by using a basic try-except. I fully agree it's kind of a dumb question, but that's your fault.

Comment: lol if the downvote matters to you that much I will give that back to you. consider first that you have identified a portion of my question ignored the rest, provided no insight if there is a known method or class for this in numpy. Your proposed answer demonstrated no working code or insight and no reference to applicable materials on the topics discussed or how you would achieve your outcome . Dumb question no, you need to respect others more and do more research if your aim is to assist and not just accrue meaningless points, which appears to be your current goal based on your answer.